# Android tab bar visible in non-tab activities

Tags: android, tabbar, visible

I have a problem with tab bar visibility in non-tab bar activities. How to set tab bar in non tab activities?

code

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);




    TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_id1");
    TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_id2");
    TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_id3");

    firstTabSpec.setIndicator("First").setContent(new Intent(this,FirstTab.class));
    secondTabSpec.setIndicator("Second ").setContent(new Intent(this,SecondTab.class));
    thirdTabSpec.setIndicator("Third").setContent(new Intent(this,ThirdTab.class));


    tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(thirdTabSpec);
```

This is the code for tab bar..... I have 5 activities..firstTab,secondTab,thirdTab,fourthActivity,fifthActivity. But problem is, Tab bar visible for only 3 tab activities but not in fourthActivity and fifthActivity. How to show the tab bar in reamaining activities? please help me.....

Thanks...

Comment: tab bar should visible in all screens other than tab activities.

Comment: this will help you https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=sIG&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&spell=1&q=navigation+inside+tab+bar+android&sa=X&ei=g5B2UJHRKIyHrAeFpoHADw&ved=0CCAQvwUoAA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. Change First Tab Activity as a Tab Group. Set Default Tab Group activity as First Tab.

```
firstTabSpec.setIndicator("First").setContent(new Intent(this,TABGROUP.class));
secondTabSpec.setIndicator("Second ").setContent(new Intent(this,SecondTab.class));
thirdTabSpec.setIndicator("Third").setContent(new Intent(this,ThirdTab.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take buttons on place of tabs.

Comment: Admittedly, your answer is longer than 30 characters, so it's above the SO minimum. But frankly, I wish it were more comprehensive. Do you mean "Use buttons instead of tabs"? How can it be achieved? How will it solve tab bar visibility?